# CSS displayed only on TOR browser not other

Tags: css, firefox, tor

On mobiles i need to get rid of that line at left of the **Essex County** info. So i go to the dev tools and it seems a quick update:
[image: Firefox dev tools]

so i did the updates on the file like this

[image: css on editor]

**BUT** it is still displayed on Edge, Chrome & Firefox **BUT** not on TOR browser:

[image: CSS ok on TOR]

This has driven me crazy for so long. Also when I inspect the location of the css file I modified it points to a different location I can't find on the FTP Server.
So I am not sure how to get rid of that line from the rest of the browsers.

Any idea please?

the website is: https://spineandsportsmed.com/locations/

Comment: I'm guessing it's due to tor refusing to process any media queries properly in order to remove any chance of people getting browser information.

Comment: Also, you should be copy-pasting code in the question and add comments labeling the code sections instead of taking a screenshot. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5923139)